# Can't change file descriptor max limit in Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64

Tags: ulimit

Trying to increase system wide file descriptor count on Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64, currently running as a droplet in DigitalOcean. [Following the process outlined here](https://docs.arweave.org/info/mining/mining-guide#install-the-miner); quick summary below:

1. Use `ulimit -n`... prints 1024 ✅
2. Add `fs.file-max=900000` and `fs.nr_open=9000001` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`
3. Execute `sysctl -p` to make the changes take effect.
4. Use `ulimit -n` to double check the changes... prints 1024 ❌ should have printed **900000**!.

I would expect at step 4 to get something other than 1024! What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Trying to increase the file descriptor max limit on Ubuntu 20, however, changing sysctl doesn't have an effect. I am curious what's going on and why my change doesn't get reflected. Do you have any specific questions I could answer?

Comment: Asking about Ubuntu server, version 20 (not Core for embedded devices). What's the correct way to clarify this question? Edit: Updated title to include Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64.

Comment: Ah, I see — clarified in title; thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

The max file descriptor limit and the ulimit are separate numbers.
The ulimit by default is set to 1024 and should probably not be changed in most circumstances because some older libraries have internal hardcoded arrays for file descriptors and may crash if you increase above 1024.

The ulimit for open files is a soft limit and can be raised either manually or by the process itself.  For example, `ulimit -n 9000`

By setting `fs.file-max=900000` you are probably actually *lowering* the open file limit, which by default on Ubuntu 20.04 is much higher.